# Java regular expression: how to include '-'

Tags: java, regex

I am using this pattern and matching a string.

```
String s = "//name:value /name:value";
if (s.matches("(//?\\s*\\w+:\\w+\\s*)+")) {
  // it fits
}
```

This works properly.
But if I want to have a string like `"/name-or-address:value/name-or-address:value"` which has this '-' in second part, it doesn't work.
I am using `\w` to match `A-Za-z_`, but how can I include `-` in that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[\w-]` to combine both `\w` and `-`.

Note that `-` should always be at the beginning or end of a character class, otherwise it will be interpreted as defining a range of characters (for instance, `[a-z]` is the range of characters from `a` to `z`, whereas `[az-]` is the three characters `a`,`z`,and`-`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers your question but why not replacing \w+ with (\w|-)+ or [\w-]+ ?

Comment: No reason to use a group and or operator here - character classes should be defined using `[]`, not OR's.

Answer (score 0):

`[-\w]` (Or in a string, `[-\\w]`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 if (s.matches("/(/|\\w|-|:\\w)+")) {
```